# What to expect during migration from Java 6 to Java 7

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection

We're migrating from **Java 6u17** to **Java 7u45**.
The application is run under **Weblogic 12.1.1.0**, it has tons of legacy code and dependencies (versions of which we left unchanged).
After recompilation we got the app running.
At first it seemed all fine but in a while we ran into '**gc overhead limit exceeded**'. It emerged from one of the batch jobs that worked perfectly fine for years under Java 6_17 (and it hasn't been changed since).
Obviously there is more to just 'recompile and run', at least one has to consider GC tweaking.

So the question stands, has anyone experienced problems (or maybe surprises) during the migration of an enterprise app from Java 6 to Java 7?
Or are there any guidelines/good practices?
PS: This is purely practical question. Let's omit discussion of pros and cons, language changes and so on.

Comment: What's new in Java 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html

Comment: Migration from Java 6 to Java 7: https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/migrating_from_java_se_6

Answer (score 2):

I just yesterday upgraded my code from 6.17SE to 7.51SE (that is, recompiled it). Is it an enterprise app? No. It's a library of about 500 classes, that almost entirely uses `java.lang`, `util`, and `io`, with a smattering of `java.lang.reflect` and a pinch of `java.net`.

The not-so-hardest part was re-pointing javac, the CLASSPATH and PATH to the correct JDK. You'll find compilation errors be more verbose, which is, at first impression, a slight improvement. (I can't comment on garbage collection tweaking.)

Not a single change was necessary in any of my code, which is not surprising. From the ["migration" link](https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/migrating_from_java_se_6), as provided by @Andremoniy:

> Almost all existing programs should run on Java SE 7 without modification. However, there are some minor potential incompatibilities in the JRE and JDK that involve rare circumstances and "corner cases" that are documented here for completeness: 
>   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities.

As far as language improvements (which I know you don't need advice on, but I'm going to mention because it's so related), I'm likely to first take advantage of [diamond generics inference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html), [catching multiple exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) and [auto-closeable try blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html).

Good luck.